# How do I wrap an object in Python? (or is it monkey-patching?)

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm using python-docx to automate my work. I'm trying to make my own class, wrapping the docx.document.Document class, so I have an object that inherit everything from the parent class but also allow me to write custom functions in it. Here is my guess on how to make it work:

```
class WrappedDoc(docx.document.Document):
    def __new__(cls, _docx=None):
        doc = docx.Document(_docx)
        return doc
        
    def test(self):
        return 1

doc = WrappedDoc()
print(doc.test())
```

It doesn't print the result of 1, I guess it is expected because doc is just an unwrapped object. But how do I make it work?

EDIT: Found the solution. I guess I do wrapping wrong. The solution I found uses **getattr**.

```
class WrappedDoc(docx.document.Document):
    def __init__(self, docx_=None):
        self._doc = docx.Document(docx_)
        
    def __getattr__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        return self._doc.__getattribute__(__name)
                
    def test(self):
        return 1
```

Comment: What does it print instead?

Comment: Why are you implementing `__new__` that way? Just remove that and the inheritance should work as expected. This is neither wrapping nor monkey patching (which is not the same thing as wrapping), you are simply trying to use inheritance

Comment: "I'm trying to make my own class, wrapping the docx.document.Document class, so I have an object that inherit everything from the parent class but also allow me to write custom functions in it." Generally speaking, it is one or the other - either you are using inheritance or you are writing some sort of wrapper. That is up to you. In either case, you probably don't want to implement `__new__`.

Comment: I mean, that solves your immediate problem, but in this case, you absolutely should not be inheriting from `class WrappedDoc(docx.document.Document):`, again, **you either wrap the object or you inherit from it, not both**

Comment: The kind of wrapping you describe is just ordinary inheritance. (It is possible to use composition and delegation, instead.) There is nothing preventing you from adding new methods in a subclass. This also has nothing to do with the third-party library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're doing incorrectly here is that you are creating a new object with `__new__` but you never initialise `self` with `__init__`.

I don't even think you need `__new__` here at all. For example, check the following:

```
class Foo(list):
    
    def test(self):
        return 1

a = Foo([])
a.test()   # returns 1 as expected
```

**EDIT:** I've been corrected and here you don't even need the `__init__` method. When you attempt to create an instance of your new class, if it doesn't have its own initialiser, Python's method resolution order will result in base class' `__init__` being run instead.

So everything is even simpler.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to implement `__init__` here either, if all it is doing is calling `super().__init__(it)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, oh yeah, Right. If we don't define `__init__` it will just follow the MRO and use the base class' initialiser?

Comment: yes, of course. it just inherits `__init__` from the superclass